# The problem of using negative numbers (hyphen sign and minus sign) in c#

Tags: c#, iis, minus

I have a problem with the negetive sign. When I run the program in the development environment, in mathematical calculations, negative numbers are shown with a hyphen sign (‐), but when I publish the program and place it on IIS, negative numbers are shown with a minus sign (−) instead of hyphen (‐) sign.As a result, C# gets an error in converting to double type. Where does this problem come from?

i use c# and vscode for development, and the IIS(v.10) is also on the 2019 server

minus  sign (−)

hyphen sign (‐)

Comment: You could setup a CultureInfo where `.NumberFormat.NegativeSign = "−"`, then use `double.TryParse()` passing that CultureInfo (IIRC, the *standard* negative sign should be also respect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NumberFormatInfo` allows you to set specific formatting for

- Currency
- Number
- Percent

display. It is highly related to `Globalization` & `Culture`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo?view=net-7.0

What you are looking for is the „NegativeSign“ property, where you should assign your application **explicitly** a new NFI instance to fix the issue.

In your case, the likely reason is some sort of localization mismatch where the system uses *implicitly* NFI Culture 1 in Development and in Production *implicitly* NFI Culture 2:

E.g. you develop on a machine that has its system setup to be in German and then deploy on a server that is setup in English. In this specific language example -to illustrate this to you- the usual error is a mix up between decimal separators e.g. 1.000,00 (DE) and 1,000.00 (EN). It very likely is down the same ally with your negative sign issue.

Comment: tanks @philipp-elhaus, i used this code and solved my problem: var defaultDateCulture = "fa-IR";
var ci = new CultureInfo(defaultDateCulture);
ci.NumberFormat.NegativeSign="-";